# How to generate random CSS values for a javascript created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry if the title might sound a little rough but i couldn't be more specific. 
I have recently found [this](http://www.cssscript.com/fully-responsive-background-slideshow-pure-javascript-pureslider/) cool slider tutorial and what i intent to do before implanting it on my own page is to change it in a way that instead of small circles at the bottom we see small squares with different widths (so it may look more like a 2D barcode).
so far i could turn them into squares by removing border-radius but i have no other idea how to make each one's width dynamically different.
i tracked it to somewhere in the javascript where the navigation buttons (which are basically) are created :

```
        this.vars.slides.forEach(function(s,i){
        var e=document.createElement("li"),r=document.createElement("a");
```

do you have any idea on how to apply such style?

Comment: what about e.style.width = "120px" or r.style.width="25%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with CSS, without having to modify the JavaScript. Here's a little demo:

```css
ul {list-style: none;}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #000;
}
li:nth-child(2n) {width: 5px;}
li:nth-child(3n) {width: 15px;}
li:nth-child(4n) {width: 20px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```